# Mount NTFS volume on two different servers

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, storage-area-network, ntfs, fibre-channel

We mounted an NTFS volume on two Windows 2008R2 servers. This volume is on a MD Dell storage array, connected to servers with Fiber Chanel.

It worked a while, but now we get some errors like "corrupted filesystem" etc. On one server we can browse all folders (but we can't create any new file), and on the other server, we can't browse all folders.

I did a chkdsk /f on one server; it corrected a lot of errors like this one:

> Replacing invalid security id with default security id for file 2155.

Now I can create new files, but it's still unusable from the second server (where we can't use chkdsk, because it says "used by another process").

So, can we (safely) mount a NTFS volume on two servers?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q: Can we (safely) mount a NTFS volume on two servers?

A: No you cannot.

You need to use a clustered file system if you want to mount the volume on multiple simultaneous clients.

If you do not want to use a clustered file system then you can mount the volume on one client (server) and create shared folders on it that other clients can access.

Comment: Hello, ok it was my opinion. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 4):

> So, can we (safely) mount a NTFS volume on two servers?

Not unless you're using Windows Failover Clustering with applications that support it. What you're seeing is expected when you present the same NTFS to two non-clustered servers.

Comment: Hello, ok thanks. I can't mark 2 answers as good ones, so I randomly chosed the joeqwerty's one. Thanks!